# Determine the size of the bordering rectangle of the ComboBox Drop-Down Button

Tags: c#, combobox, size

I would like to be able to check whether the user clicked the Drop-Down Button of the ComboBox in the MouseClick event handler.

I could not find the size and coordinates of the bordering rectangle of the Drop-Down Button. I am using WinForms.

The task is to check whether the Drop-Down List dropped down (opened, made the items visible) as a result of a programmatic statement: comboBox1.DroppedDown = true; or as the result of the user pressing the Drop-Down Button. Is there any other better way to ascertain this?

Comment: You're going to need to specify what kind of UI framework you are using (WinForms, WPF, Win/RT, some kind of web framework (in which case the browser figures into it). The OS may affect things. The version of the Framework (or Core)... How does your second paragraph relate to the first?

Comment: @Flydog57 I am using WinForms.

Comment: Have you looked at the `DropDown` event? You don't get much info in a `MouseClick` handler. What's the significance of your second paragraph (size & coordinates)

Comment: @Flydog57 The significance of size & coordinates of the Drop-Down Button's bordering rectangle is that in the MouseClick handler I can get the click location and then check whether this location falls within the surface of the Drop-Down Button's bordering rectangle.

Comment: [ComboBox.DropDown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.dropdown?view=netframework-4.8&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.DropDown)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%253Dv4.8)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue)

Comment: [ComboBox.DropDownClosed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.dropdownclosed?view=netframework-4.8&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.DropDownClosed)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%253Dv4.8)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue)

Comment: The correct way to do this (as @dr.null and I have pointed out) is to use the `DropDown` event. Someone with intimate knowledge of the ComboBox has properly covered all the cases and raised an event specifically for your case.

Comment: @dr.null The problem with the ComboBox.DropDown event is that it occurs in both cases: when the user presses the Drop-Down Button but also when the Drop-Down List is dropped down as a result of the statement: comboBox1.DroppedDown = true; What I need is a way to find out which of the two it is.

Comment: I See. You can do for example, add a class `bool` field, set to `true` using the answer below (you need to add reference to the `Accessibility` library and import the namespace `using Accessibility;`) or by p/invoke `GetComboBoxInfo` to get the button bounds from the `COMBOBOXINFO` structure.  Use the `bool` field where you want to determine whether the list was dropped by the button, and assign `false` to the field in the `ComboBox.DropDownClosed` event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your last edit, @dr.null comment might solve your requirement. But still you want to make sure that user clicked on the arrow part of the drop down, the following code will do the job.

[image]

Notice that the position of the dropdown button part will return as the position in the screen.

```
    private void comboBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        const int COMBOBOX_DROPDOWN_BUTTON_ACC_ITEM_INDEX = 2;
        var comboBox = ((ComboBox)sender);
        IAccessible accessibilityObjectOfComboBox = comboBox.AccessibilityObject;
        accessibilityObjectOfComboBox.accLocation(
            out int x,
            out int y,
            out int width,
            out int height,
            COMBOBOX_DROPDOWN_BUTTON_ACC_ITEM_INDEX);
        var button = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
        var clickedPoint = new Rectangle(new Point(MousePosition.X, MousePosition.Y), new Size(1, 1));
        var IHit = button.IntersectsWith(clickedPoint);
        if (IHit)
            MessageBox.Show("Happy to be helpful");
    }
```

Comment: I am sorry but the accessibilityObjectOfComboBox.accLocation does not compile. I was unable to find any documentation about this. I added the using Accessibility; namespace but it did not help, though it recognized the IAccessible accessibilityObjectOfComboBox = comboBox.AccessibilityObject; statement.

Comment: It was my fault. I forgot to mention that I am working with Visual Studio 2010. I checked your method with Visual Studio 2017 and it worked fine. Thank you very much for the time and effort.